# Problem updating records via anonymous apex

Tags: trigger, update, before-trigger, execute-anonymous

I ran anonymous apex to update 50k records. This is my query..

```
update[select account__c from orders__c where account__c=null and ship_to__c!=null limit 1000];
```

At one point of time at around 11k there's no more update. I failed to find any solution. But when I tried using **offset** I could further update...

```
update[select account__c from orders__c where account__c=null and sap_ship_to__c!=null limit 1000 offset 1000];
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing anything?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Salesforce documentation on [governor limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), maximum of 50K records can be retrieved via SOQL queries, but only 10K can be processed by DML actions in a any execution context. Using `OFFSET` will only get you 2K records further as maximum value for SOQL query OFFSET parameter is [2000](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm).

If you are looking for solution to adhoc problem (i.e. you need to do a one-time update of the records) then you are better of adding a limit of 10K to your SOQL query and filtering out records that were last updated within say 5 minutes.

If you need to do this on a regular basis, then a scheduled batch class would be one of the ways forward.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the info. But how do I cover all the record?

Comment: Please see updated answer above